# split with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

below is something I am trying to do with JavaScript.

If I have string like

```
str = "how are you? hope you are doing good" ;
```

now I want to split it with ? (or . or !)  but I dont want to lose the "?". Instead I want to break the string just after the question mark such a way that question mark is with the first segment that we have. also after the ? or / or ! there needs to be a \s (space) in order to break it into segments

```
after splitting str what should I get is

["how are you?","hope you are doing good"]
```

I am not sure if it can be done with Javascript split() function ,please help.

Comment: We could have done `str.split(/(?<=\?)\s+/);` but unfortunately javascript doesn't support lookbehind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
str.match(/\S[^?]*(?:\?+|$)/g)

["how are you?", "hope you are doing good"]
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you chose to use `\S[^?]*` over `[^?]+`?

Comment: just to strip leading whitespaces, @Kevin.

Comment: Ahh okay, makes sense. Initially read it wrong. Maybe it's time for bed. Anyway, this is definitely the way to do it. Green check mark here!

Comment: Nice and simple! But fails with two "?" in a row, e.g. `"how are you?? hope you are doing good"` => `["how are you?", "? hope you are doing good"]` If you drop the whitespace thing (`\S`), that problem goes away (and you can just clean it after).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, updated `\?` to `\?+` to support that `??` pattern, If I drop `\S` it would return 2nd one as `" hope you are doing good"`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, most straight-forward way I can see is to just lose the "?" and add it back:

```
var parts, n;
parts = str.split("?");
for (n = parts.length - 2; n >= 0; --n) { // Skip the last one
    parts[n] += "?";
}
if (str.charAt(str.length-1) == "?") {    // If it ended with "?", add it back
    parts[parts.length-1] += "?";
}
```

Alternately, though, there's a way via RegExp. **Edit** Removed mine, [S.Mark's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816553/split-with-javascript/2816579#2816579) is *so much better*.

Answer (score 2):

...

```
var str = "how are you? hope you are doing good";
var data = str.split('?');
data[0] += '?';

alert(data[0]); // result: how are you?
alert(data[1]); // result: hope you are doing good
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a regex, as in:

```
str = "how are you? hope you are doing good";
var tokens = str.split(/(\?)/)
```

but this wil result in the question marks in their own token: `how are you,?, hope you are,?, doing good`

A better option is:

```
var tokens = str.match(/[^?]+\?*/g)
```

This will also keep multiple question marks: `"hello??? how are you?"`

Answer (score 1):

If JS supported regexp look-behinds all you'd need is split by `/(?<=\?)/`, but unfortunately it doesn't. However you can very easily get the same behavior with the `match()` function:

```
var str = "how are you? hope you are doing good";
var data = str.match(/(?!$)[^?]*\??/g);
```

Will give you `["how are you?", " hope you are doing good"]`

Comment: I tried to change this regex to in order to work with . & ! as well , for example instead of only ? if the condition is like "\?\s" or "\!\s" or "\.\s" . in this case what would be the expression ? so that for sentence like  "This is a good example to show? this example to show is good.ok do it" then what we get is  ["This is a good example to show?","this example to show is good.ok do it"] as there is no space after the . (fullstop)

Answer (score 1):

another idea:

```
var str = "how are you? hope you are doing good",
    strsplit = str.split('?').join('?#').split('#');
alert(strsplit) //=> how are you?, hope you are doing good
```

or (based on answer & comment from [kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi))

```
var str = "how are you? All right?? Hope so???";
alert(str.replace(/([\?(1,}][^\?$])/g,'$1#!#').split(' #!#'));
  //=>how are you?,All right??,Hope so???
```

Comment: might as well `replace(/\?/g, '?###')`, but you're taking a risk if the string already has # signs.